# Integer as key for Map Reduce in Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a collection in Mongodb like the following:

```
{_id: {"thread": "abc"}, "value": 1}
{_id: {"thread": "cdf"}, "value": 1}
{_id: {"thread": "edf"}, "value": 1}
```

I tried to map reduce trying to key on value, hoping for an output as follows:

```
{id_: {"value": 1}, value: 3}
```

MAP:

```
function() {
var key = {value : this.value};
emit(key, 1);
};
```

REDUCE:

```
function(key, values) {
var sum = 0;
values.forEach(function(value) {
sum += value;});
return sum;
};
```

**EDIT** Orignial question: Map Reduce didn't work is not valid anymore. It was a connection problem and not Map Reduce. Thanks to everyone for the extra bit of information.

unfortunately, that didn't work and gave an some output as follows:

```
{u'_id': {u'value': None}, u'value': 1160856.0}
```

Isn't it possible to key on an integer value?? I read the map reduce documentation on Mongodb but couldn't find an info related on the data type of key.

Comment: What is your map/reduce function?

Comment: Is perhaps the lack of integer support in the mongo interactive shell biting you? See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell#Overview-TheMongoDBInteractiveShell-SomeNotesonDatatypesintheShell

Comment: @Thilo I edited the question and added them.

Comment: @Koert Well, if thats the case, it is biting me. I am trying to convert the integer into a string and then storing.

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in the field names somewhere? Are they actually called `value` like in the example?

Comment: @Koert is correct. The mongo shell converts all integer types to double and stores them as such.

Comment: @Thilo there is no typo, I checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running your map/reduce from the MongoDB shell you may be running into a feature/issue (opinions vary on that one ;) ) where the shell converts all integer types to double and stores them as such. There is currently no real workaround other than invoking your m/r from something other than the shell. That said, if I run your m/r I get this :

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "value" : 1
        },
        "value" : 3
}
```

Which seems to be what you're trying to do. I'm not sure if it is or not. Make sure you're running the latest db version and such.

Comment: But why would the result then group everything under "None". Should it not still mostly work, except that key and count are doubles now?

Comment: Im using Python to Map reduce. Is there a easy solution to m/r on the value field as key?

Comment: @Thilo, yes thats my question too.

Comment: @Thilo Didn't look at the m/r itself. As far as I can tell the m/r works from the shell. I'll edit my answer to show the result I'm getting.